# Docker in virtualbox

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have a following scenario:

Windows 7 machine, with an ubuntu virtual machine through virtual box.

I want to know what are the best options for running docker inside the ubuntu?
Can I just install the docker to the ubuntu? Or should I use docker-machine?

The official specs left me confused by saying:

> Machine is currently the only way to run Docker on Mac or Windows

So according to that, it would mean I do need the docker-machine, since my base system is Windows?

Why couldn't I just install docker to the virtual machine ubuntu, and use it directly there?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can but haven't tried this myself. The comment about Docker Machine is related to not being able to run Docker directly on the Windows OS. Docker Machine is spinning up a headless Virtualbox instance of boot2docker with a convenient cli to access it.